# Trying to transfer older version of mediawiki to new server

Tags: backup, debian, mediawiki, move

So, in college I had a Debian server which used to host a wiki, with mediawiki version 1.9. This server stopped working, and all I have now is its HD. I want to transfer this wiki to a new server, which also runs Debian, but I can't do that with Debian's current stable version of mediawiki, 1.15, because it is not possible to transfer a wiki to another version of mediawii.

So, my idea is to install mediawiki 1.9 on the new server, and then move the wiki. But I am having problems with installing it.

When I go to http://my_hostname/config/index.php, to configure the new wiki, so that I can transfer the other one, I get the following message, and nothing happens:

```
Checking environment...

Please include all of the lines below when reporting installation problems.
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze8 installed"
```

I really don't have a clue on what is wrong. ANY help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am wondering... Do I have to do this initial configuration? Can I just copy ALL the mediawiki files from the old server to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Like you commented yourself, it would certainly be worth a try to using your existing configuration. The configuration is typically some site preferences and database configuration, so make sure dat your database is setup in the same way as before.

Regarding your configuration problems, maybe php filters away the errors. You can check this by searching for `error_reporting` in your `php.ini`.

Comment: So, I transfered all mediawiki's files from the old server to the new one, and also the mySQL database. Now all I get is a blank screen, when I access the wiki. Any ideas?

Comment: Again, a blank screen is often the cause of bad `error_reporting`. Also, the existing configuration might expect url rewriting: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL#Recommended_how-to_guide_.28setup_used_on_Wikipedia.29

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the instructions at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading. Probably no point in trying to install at MediaWiki 1.9.

You may want to do a clean install of MediaWiki 1.18.1 first just to make sure your system is ready, all dependencies met, etc.

Comment: We ended up doing a clean install of Mediawiki 1.18.1, in fact. Thank you both for the advices!